# Are flyway migrations mutable?

Tags: flyway

We have a migration for populating a table, but as we are just starting development this data changes frequently. So we are wondering if we could just update such a migration script and ask [flyway](https://flywaydb.org) to rollback it (the previous version) and execute it again (the new version). In fact, if this is possible, that is, if migrations are mutable, then we imagine it would be needed to rollback and execute again every subsequent migrations to be sure they haven't been affected. We believe this could avoid the proliferation of migrations during development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeatable migrations are what you're looking for. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/repeatable